# Working on overdrive (struggle to take a break) - affecting health

Tags: work-environment, anxiety, psychology

Firstly, apologies if this is the wrong site but it is related to work, but could also be related to psychology so please feel free to move if necessary.

By trade I am a software developer so my job requires constant mental exertion. I know of other developers who are able to take breaks and not overthink things - but I am constantly overthinking. I also work on overdrive, like I try to work a million miles an hour. This is having an affect on my mental health, I suffer from IBS and anxiety and working like this is actually causing my body to go into overdrive (it's affecting my gut, let's say).

I've been to doctors several times and the IBS/gut side of things is nothing to worry about apparently, but I need to address it.

I can't let things drop. If I don't understand something I will work hours upon end until I do understand. I can't go to sleep without thinking about it. I find it incredibly hard to switch off and when I'm given a new project or an issue arises with something I have programmed I am instantly on it and want to fix it there and then.

I have a very good social life (may surprise you given what I've just written) and do enjoy my spare time, but does anyone have any advice on how to calm down?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while very valid, it should be answered by a medical and/or mental health professional.

Comment: @nvoigt I think an answer that describes how to seek medical help makes sense though.

Comment: Closing is unnecessary. My "calm down" comment may come across over the top. The problem is the pressure I maybe put on myself to know all the answers as I don't really have a team to help. Don't get me wrong, I love my job, I just need to handle my time better I believe as per @Snow has suggested.

Comment: Also why is it so annoyingly common to want to close questions. It's a work related question. I stated it is mental too. Surely both go hand in hand. Let people discuss.

Comment: Yep this is the description of severe stress. While there are medicines that will shut those reactions down,  they usually have profound side effects, so I would say save that option for emergency use in acute episodes (should any arise). 2 things to look at: (1) Creating a feeling of safety within the work world, where things are organized so that you can walk away for a few days and truly believe deep down everything is fine (2) Examine sources of anxiety outside work, because it spills over big time. This may well involve reaching deep into uncomfortable places. Multi year life project.

Comment: Ricky, work related does not mean we can help. If you broke your leg while at work, we could not help you either. We could help you how to inform HR, but if you're hurting and it's broken, you need to see a doctor. Mental and Physical Health are not that different. Right now you are hurting and your physical doctors told you to seek help. You need to see a mental health professional.

Comment: I think I just put too much pressure on myself. My job/company are extremely relaxed. Again, it's not just work related. I own on my own software development projects and have the same feelings if I do not know of the solution or it's something I'm yet to learn. Some of these comments sound like I'm on the brink of a mental breakdown, this is really not the case, but maybe that's how the post has come across.

Comment: You went to a doctor for your gut problems. Where you close to an organ failure? Was your body close to a physical breakdown? No. But they were problems and you had them addressed by a professional. The same goes for mental health. Are you a raving lunatic? No. But you have problems (who doesn't) and why would you not seek professional help? If your doctor had prescribed antibiotics, you would take them. Instead they told you to seek help with a mental health professional. You should do so.

Answer (score 4):

This is something I've dealt with myself.

As Joe said in the comments, getting professional help is paramount.  Do this ASAP.  You cannot be "always on", or the effect of stress hormones will make you as much of a wreck as I was by the time I turned 50.  0/5 would not reccomend.

One of my favorite books is "Rhinoceros success", which is recommended for salesmen and executives.  It has an entire chapter dedicated to renewal and the importance of down time.  Whether it is called "Sharpening the axe" or the plethora of other names it is given, taking time to renew yourself, your connections with family and friends, and your interests is as necessary to your job as actually doing your job is.

Seek professional help, and take this seriously.  You are only beginning to feel the effects, in time, they will become more serious.  Take care of it now before anything becomes permanent.

Answer (score 3):

As with the majority of advice you've probably seem before, the simple answer is enforce time management.

You said you have a good social life, so you're able to break away from work and do something else.  So what you need to do is schedule more and keep to that.  Even if you're not interacting with other people - find time to do something else at least with your body and brain (get outside, take a drive, watch TV, play video games, whatever gets you away from Notepad++).

And stick with it.

My employer is extremely hot on getting people away from work for their own mental health - as you've seen, it's affecting your health and also, as a consequence, your efficiency.

Also consider that working your way into a breakdown isn't expected of you by your employer - you're not going to get rewarded for all of the extra work you're doing.

Another way of thinking about this:

> Do the bulk of your work in the time when you're actually being paid to work

If you work, or commit major thinking time to work outside of your working hours, you're not being paid for that work.

Comment: I think you're right. It's something I struggle with, to get away from the laptop. If I know the answer I can do this but if I am struggling to think of the answer I can't seem to pull away until I get there. Its not actually the job either, I am like this in normal life too, whether working for an employer or working on my own projects.

Comment: @Ricky I often "backburner" issues in my downtime. If I get far enough to have a high-level idea of how to resolve a problem, I'm happy with that - I know that I'll grind the detail when I actually get to work.

Comment: It's a little like telling an addict to "just not do it" and "stick with not doing it". I mean it isn't wrong. But it's not actually a helpful answer either, because if the OP could just do that, they would not ask for help.

Comment: @nvoigt - no, it's not. Enforcing time management is key here - and it's something I have thought of previously but need to do better, and this help clarifies that.

Comment: @Snow - "If you work, or commit major thinking time to work outside of your working hours, you're not being paid for that work." That's the thing I struggle with. Again, maybe time management as you say. Work or not, I struggle to pull away until I have solved everything that is in mind at that time. My company are extremely relaxed and there is little stress to deliver - it's myself doing this. But it's more noticeable at work hence the post, because I work 8 hours a day doing it.

Comment: @Snow are you a developer? I ask as I think it's quite common with developers.

Comment: @Ricky Yes, I am.

Comment: @Ricky, If you have trouble letting go of the technical issues you are working on, try to consciously park your investigations at the end of the working day. Write down what you found out so far and what your next avenue of inquiry is and then tell yourself that you will pick it up from there the next working day and deliberately start thinking about something else (preferably not work-related).

Answer (score 3):

Things that have helped me break out of roughly similar feelings. Note they have absolutely nothing to do with work (or more generally nothing to do with the area in which the stress manifests).

- Exercise with lots of breathing, especially swimming
- Doing something that gives feeling of accomplishment and restoring control outside of work, big or small - e.g. attend to a difficult family relationship, deal with a long standing finance issue, build a piece of furniture, learn a technically challenging sport skill, fix something in house or car, rearrange living room, get new curtains that change the color of the light, get a haircut
- Spend time with other people having struggles of their own. This can be the gateway to empathy, patience, understanding, seeing life patterns over long time scales... all of which are needed for the self